# SaveAs password protected document without password - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am opening a password protected Word document using the below macro in Excel, then I want to save a copy of the document without the password protection. Currently, I am still prompted for the original password when I try and open the newly saved document.

```
Dim DPObj
Dim DPApp As Object
Dim YourOwnPassword As String
Dim DocPath As String
DocSrcPath = "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Sources\SourceDoc.doc"
DocTgtPath = "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Targets\TargetDoc.doc"
YourOwnPassword = "TestPWD"
Set DPApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
'Open Password enabled document
DPDoc = DPApp.Documents.Open(DocSrcPath, PasswordDocument:=YourOwnPassword)
'Make some changes to the document. 
'Save the edited document without a password
DPApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 DocTgtPath
```

Does anybody know how to make it so that the `TargetDoc.doc` is not still password protected?

Comment: Why doesn't the current code work?

Comment: When i open the new document it is prompting for the password "TestPWD". Which i don't wanted to

Comment: You want to remove the password in the saved document? Try using `DPApp.Unprotect` before saving.

Comment: @Vincent G
Getting error 
        ** Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method **

Comment: Sorry, I mean `DPApp.ActiveDocument.Unprotect`

Comment: @Vincent G: Command is working but still prompting for the password if i try to open the new document

Comment: Using a blank password should work: `DPApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 DocTgtPath, Password:=""`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a blank password should work:

```
DPApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 DocTgtPath, Password:=""
```